# html table joining and freezing table header?

Tags: html

I have 5 tables..and all these tables have the same column header and for each row the first row acts as a row header and instead this row header too is same for all the tables..so i just want to join all these tables with only one column-header for all these tables ..and also i want to freeze this column header so that the data inside this can be scrollable..

th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Below css for tr

```
.lockedrows
    {
        position:relative;
        cursor: default; 
        top: expression(document.getElementById("tbl-container").scrollTop-2);
        z-index: 20;
    }
```

`tbl-container`  is id of div inside which u have to make ur table